# is there a way you can have a backend in a fully offline mobile app with react native

Tags: react-native, native, offline, mobile-development

I am trying to layout the approach and various technologies I would use to create a "fully" offline mobile app with react native. I have settled on the database(SQLite) and frontend frameworks. Seeing as I can't really have a "backend" because nothing is going to be connected to the internet. The app will be taking data from the user, "manipulating" it, and giving it back to the user. I'm just confused where the "manipulation" comes in if there isn't a backend.

Documentation online regarding offline mobile apps isn't very extensive.

Comment: If you're completely offline, then you can't have a backend. That leaves only one place where **everything** must happen: your program itself, running on the phone, in your case, your react-native app. Instead of just calling a web service to manipulate the data that gives you a result, you do the data processing yourself. IE, a rich client instead of a dumb frontend.

Comment: If app is fully offline then there will be no backend at all but i am not clear what type of data and data will be needed to accessible for other then logged in user?

Comment: Thank you, I thought this as well I just needed to confirm.